# Creating instance of Read type class in Haskell for custom data type

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I have a custom data type `Foo = Foo{ a :: Int, b :: Int}` and I'm trying to make Foo a custom instance of read. I already have a function `bar :: String -> Foo` and I tried doing this:

```
instance Read (Foo a b) where
    read s = bar s
```

but I'm getting the following error when I load my file into GHCi to test it: `Fraction.hs:11:1: read' is not a (visible) method of class Read'`

Could someone tell me what the problem is and how I can actually instantiate this type?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [Read](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#t:Read) typeclass doesn't declare `read` directly; instead, it defines `readsPrec`, which supports precedence (this is important when `read`ing a value of a complex data type involving elements of other types).  The definition you get when you use `deriving (Read)` looks roughly like

```
instance (Read a) => Read (Tree a) where

    readsPrec d r =  readParen (d > app_prec)
                     (\r -> [(Leaf m,t) |
                             ("Leaf",s) <- lex r,
                             (m,t) <- readsPrec (app_prec+1) s]) r
                  ++ readParen (d > up_prec)
                     (\r -> [(u:^:v,w) |
                             (u,s) <- readsPrec (up_prec+1) r,
                             (":^:",t) <- lex s,
                             (v,w) <- readsPrec (up_prec+1) t]) r
      where app_prec = 10
            up_prec = 5
```

(this obviously for a `Tree` data type, but similar rules apply for other user-defined ADTs).  (Also, the above is a slight lie:  GHC actually uses a different implementation, but the above is the kind of thing you should do unless you're willing to dig around inside of GHC.)

`read` is defined in terms of `readsPrec` and `readList` (the other method in `Read`, which is defaulted for every type except `Char` where it's used to read `[Char]` as a string instead of as a list of `Char`).

If the standard derivation isn't sufficient, for a type like yours that is simply a bucket of `Int`s you can ignore the precedence parameter.

BTW, `Read` and `Show` are rather slow; you may want to consider other ways to do I/O with your data.

Comment: do you have any suggestions for alternatives to read and show?

Answer (score 4):

That's because the class method that you'd probably want to implement is **readsPrec**. See here for complete info on Read typeclass: http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/Read_c.html

BTW, you should be able to just use automatic derivation and the compiler will instantiate those Read methods for you e.g.:

```
data Foo = Foo Int Int
           deriving (Read, Show)
```

Comment: I know I can do that, but I don't really like the way read gets automatically done since it is less intuitive and wanted to make a better version.