# Making a Read instance in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, typeclass, symmetry

I have a data type

```
data Time = Time {hour :: Int,
                  minute :: Int
                 }
```

for which i have defined the instance of Show as being

```
instance Show Time where
  show (Time hour minute) = (if hour > 10
                             then (show hour)
                             else ("0" ++ show hour))
                            ++ ":" ++
                            (if minute > 10
                             then (show minute)
                             else ("0" ++ show minute))
```

which prints out times in a format of `07:09`.

Now, there should be symmetry between `Show` and `Read`, so after reading (but not truly (i think) understanding) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520940/creating-instance-of-read-type-class-in-haskell-for-custom-data-type) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851275/how-to-create-instance-of-read-for-a-datatype-in-haskell), and reading the [documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Text-Read.html#t%3aRead), i have come up with the following code:

```
instance Read Time where
  readsPrec _ input =
    let hourPart = takeWhile (/= ':')
        minutePart = tail . dropWhile (/= ':')
    in (\str -> [(newTime
                  (read (hourPart str) :: Int)
                  (read (minutePart str) :: Int), "")]) input
```

This works, but the `""` part makes it seem wrong. So my question ends up being:

Can anyone explain to me the correct way to implement Read to parse `"07:09"` into `newTime 7 9` and/or show me?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'll use `isDigit` and keep your definition of Time.

```
import Data.Char (isDigit)

data Time = Time {hour :: Int,
                  minute :: Int
                 }
```

You used but didn't define `newTime`, so I wrote one myself so my code compiles!

```
newTime :: Int -> Int -> Time
newTime h m | between 0 23 h && between 0 59 m = Time h m
            | otherwise = error "newTime: hours must be in range 0-23 and minutes 0-59"
     where between low high val = low <= val && val <= high
```

---

Firstly, your show instance is a little wrong because `show $ Time 10 10` gives `"010:010"`

```
instance Show Time where
  show (Time hour minute) = (if hour > 9       -- oops
                             then (show hour)
                             else ("0" ++ show hour))
                            ++ ":" ++
                            (if minute > 9     -- oops
                             then (show minute)
                             else ("0" ++ show minute))
```

Let's have a look at `readsPrec`:

```
*Main> :i readsPrec
class Read a where
  readsPrec :: Int -> ReadS a
  ...
    -- Defined in GHC.Read
*Main> :i ReadS
type ReadS a = String -> [(a, String)]
    -- Defined in Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP
```

That's a parser - it should return the unmatched remaining string instead of just `""`, so you're right that the `""` is wrong:

```
*Main> read "03:22" :: Time
03:22
*Main> read "[23:34,23:12,03:22]" :: [Time]
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

It can't parse it because you threw away the `,23:12,03:22]` in the first read.

Let's refactor that a bit to eat the input as we go along:

```
instance Read Time where
  readsPrec _ input =
    let (hours,rest1) = span isDigit input
        hour = read hours :: Int
        (c:rest2) = rest1
        (mins,rest3) = splitAt 2 rest2
        minute = read mins :: Int
        in
      if c==':' && all isDigit mins && length mins == 2 then -- it looks valid
         [(newTime hour minute,rest3)]
       else []                      -- don't give any parse if it was invalid
```

Gives for example

```
Main> read "[23:34,23:12,03:22]" :: [Time]
[23:34,23:12,03:22]
*Main> read "34:76" :: Time
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

It does, however, allow "3:45" and interprets it as "03:45". I'm not sure that's a good idea, so perhaps we could add another test `length hours == 2`.

---

I'm going off all this split and span stuff if we're doing it this way, so maybe I'd prefer:

```
instance Read Time where
  readsPrec _ (h1:h2:':':m1:m2:therest) =
    let hour   = read [h1,h2] :: Int  -- lazily doesn't get evaluated unless valid
        minute = read [m1,m2] :: Int
        in
      if all isDigit [h1,h2,m1,m2] then -- it looks valid
         [(newTime hour minute,therest)]
       else []                      -- don't give any parse if it was invalid
  readsPrec _ _ = []                -- don't give any parse if it was invalid
```

Which actually seems cleaner and simpler to me.

This time it doesn't allow `"3:45"`:

```
*Main> read "3:40" :: Time
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
*Main> read "03:40" :: Time
03:40
*Main> read "[03:40,02:10]" :: [Time]
[03:40,02:10]
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the off-by-one error in show. This new code makes more sense, and would have been more correct, if not for the fact (which i forgot to mention), that the "smart constructor" `newTime` already does the validity checking.

Comment: @Magnap I've edited the unnecessary checks out and used newTime.

Comment: @Magnap I still need to check that I've got digits before calling `read` on the `Int`s.

Comment: Thank you. This does, however fail with a time such as `9:3` in a list, but parses it correctly individually. Overall it is more correct though. This is also a great template for a parse.

Comment: @Magnap Actually, I think it ought _not_ to parse `9:3` ever, so I edited it. The reason was that `splitAt 2 "3"` gives `("3","")`, so silently succeeds on insufficient data, whereas if it's in a list, for example `splitAt 2 "3]"` gives `("3]","")` and `"3]"` fails to be read.

Comment: Of course, and the latter code is also more simple (and fails more "correctly", thus enforcing the "spec") than the former. Thank you for guiding me on this matter.

Answer (score 5):

If the input to `readsPrec` is a string that contains some other characters after a valid representation of a `Time`, those other characters should be returned as the second element of the tuple.

So for the string `12:34 bla`, the result should be `[(newTime 12 34, " bla")]`. Your implementation would cause an error for that input. This means that something like `read "[12:34]" :: [Time]` would fail because it would call `Time`'s `readsPrec` with `"12:34]"` as the argument (because `readList` would consume the `[`, then call `readsPrec` with the remaining string, and then check that the remaining string returned by `readsPrec` is either `]` or a comma followed by more elements).

To fix your `readsPrec` you should rename `minutePart` to something like `afterColon` and then split that into the actual minute part (with `takeWhile isDigit` for example) and whatever comes after the minute part. Then the stuff that came after the minute part should be returned as the second element of the tuple.

Comment: Thanks a lot. After changing the let to (bracketed for readability)
`{hourPart = takeWhile (/= ':') input;
afterColon = tail . dropWhile (/= ':') $ input;
minutePart = takeWhile isDigit afterColon;
rest = dropWhile isDigit afterColon;}` it works wonderfully.