# Writing a proper custom read instance

Tags: haskell, typeclass, currying, deriving

Hello fellow Haskellers,

I am learning Haskell from one month now, and I am struggling in creating a custom read instance for a personnal data type.

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14006707/making-a-read-instance-in-haskell) and the [relevant chapter in Learn Yourself a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#derived-instances), here is my code snippet.

```
data Position      =  Position (Absc,Ordn) deriving (Show)
instance Read (Position) where
readsPrec _ input =
    let absc = List.filter (/='(') $ takeWhile (/=',')
        ordn = List.filter (/=')') $ tail (dropWhile (/=',') )
    in (\str -> Position ( (read (absc str) :: Int)
                       , (read (ordn str) :: Int) ) ) input
type Absc = Int
type Ordn = Int
```

My goal is to parse an input `"(1,3)"` to output something like `Position (1,3)`

I, however, get the following error messages:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘[Char]’
              with actual type ‘[Char] -> [Char]’
• Probable cause: ‘takeWhile’ is applied to too few arguments
  In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘takeWhile (/= ',')’
  In the expression: filter (/= '(') $ takeWhile (/= ',')
  In an equation for ‘absc’:
      absc = filter (/= '(') $ takeWhile (/= ',')
```

Same for the ordn function.

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘[(Position, String)]’
              with actual type ‘Position’
• In the expression:
    (\ str
       -> Position ((read (absc str) :: Int), (read (ordn str) :: Int)))
      input
  In the expression:
    let
      absc = filter (/= '(') $ takeWhile (/= ',')
      ordn = filter (/= ')') $ tail (dropWhile (/= ','))
    in
      (\ str
         -> Position ((read (absc str) :: Int), (read (ordn str) :: Int)))
        input
  In an equation for ‘readsPrec’:
      readsPrec _ input
        = let
            absc = filter (/= '(') $ takeWhile (/= ',')
            ordn = filter (/= ')') $ tail (dropWhile (/= ','))
          in
            (\ str
               -> Position ((read (absc str) :: Int), (read (ordn str) :: Int)))
              input
```

It seems that my `let` statement does not recognize `absc` and `ordn` as functions (or at least try to apply them directly, while I only want to define them as partially applied functions to apply them later at parameter `str`). I am also probably messing up with my `Position` value constructor.

I am not familiar with Haskell coding style, and I may have used some keywords and tools that I do not fully understand. Could you hint me on how to write this to make it work?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need `. takeWhile (/=',')` don't you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a bunch of errors in your code - I think you should read up a bit on the difference between `$` and `.` it is an essential thing to know when handling functions, most of your errors are due to a try to apply a function to its argument `($)` instead of concatenating functions `(.)`.

This is what I modified your code to at least type check - though I think `readsPrec` should not keep the original input but the remaining string after the parsing is done.

### Fixing the code

```
instance Read Position where
  readsPrec _ input =
      let absc = filter (/='(') . takeWhile (/=',')
          ordn = filter (/=')') . tail . dropWhile (/=',')
       in [(Position ( read (absc input) :: Int
                     , read (ordn input) :: Int), input)]
```

But seeing this makes me unhappy - isn't haskell said to be abstract, slick and really expressive. Let us give it another try

### tidying up

```
instance Read Position where
  readsPrec _ str = let ('(':absc,',':ordn') = break (==',') str
                        (ordn,')':str') = break (==')') ordn'
                     in [(Position (read absc, read ordn), str')]
```

much better, we capture that there should be the parens at the beginning and the end, but still a bit cumbersome.

### using existing functionality

Knowing that `Tuple`s are already instances of `Read`

```
instance Read Position where
  readsPrec s str = [(Position x, rest) | (x,rest) <- readsPrec s str]
```

### nice but still we can do better

Say we recently worked a bit with tuples and found the very handy module `Data.Bifunctor` that has functions `first` and `second` to transform the first and second component of a 2-tuple (any bifunctor in fact).

We can simplify the above to

```
instance Read Position where
  readsPrec s = map (first Position) . readsPrec s
```

clean and short.

Answer (score 0):

Using `show "(3,4)"::Position` returns `Position (3,4)`.
Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I tend to confuse `$` and `.` notation, but after I went through the documentation, it became clear.